# Cannot Pass CustomComboBox that inherits KryptonComboBox to a method expecting KryptonComboBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance

I have a class that inherits from KryptonComboBox for some UI changes. This class had to be created in a VB project for unrelated reasons and so was written in VB.

```
Namespace CustomStuff.Controls
    Public Class CustomComboBox
        Inherits ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonComboBox

        ''Stuff

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Then I changed a KryptonComboBox that was on my form (C#) to now be a CustomComboBox:

```
private CustomStuff.Controls.CustomComboBox cboTestBox;
this.cboTestBox = new CustomStuff.Controls.CustomComboBox();
```

I then have a method that takes a KryptonComboBox as a parameter by ref (C#):

```
public static void LoadComboBoxFromFind(ref KryptonComboBox sender)
{
    //Stuff
}
```

When I try call this method with the instance of my CustomComboBox I get the error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref CustomStuff.Controls.CustomComboBox' to 'ref ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonComboBox'
```

I did some testing and if I manually cast the CustomComboBox to a KryptonComboBox it all works fine, but this would require changing a lot of places:

```
KryptonComboBox temp = (KryptonComboBox)cboTestBox;
Utils.LoadComboBoxFromFind(ref temp);
```

Shouldn't this just work automatically since the CustomComboBox inherits the KryptonComboBox? Is there something else I should be adding to the CustomComboBox class to allow this?

EDIT:

The current workaround I'm using is the below overload method:

```
public static void LoadComboBoxFromFind(ref CustomStuff.Controls.CustomComboBox sender)
{
    KryptonComboBox temp = (KryptonComboBox)sender;
    LoadComboBoxFromFind(ref temp);
}
```

This workaround works fine, but I'd prefer a way that doesn't need this sort of cheap workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the parameter is declared `ref`.  The point of a `ref` parameter is that you can assign to it inside the method and that affects the original variable.  The original variable is type `CustomComboBox` but the parameter is type `KryptonComboBox`.  Allowing what you want implies that the code inside the method could assign a `KryptonComboBox` object to the parameter and that would successfully set the original variable of type `CustomComboBox`, which would make no sense at all.

The question is, why is that parameter declared `ref` in the first place?  Are you assigning anything to it inside the method?  If not then there's no justification for it being declared that way.  If you are setting the parameter inside the method, why?  If it actually makes sense to do so then you simply can't pass a reference of a more derived type than the parameter is declared as.

Comment: The reason it is passed by ref is the method is meant to fill values into the ComboBox. So it is affected by the method. And if what you were saying were true, then I'd get errors when it tries to assign values the way that I show at the end where it works perfectly.

Comment: No, no, no!  What I'm saying IS true.  Get rid of the `ref` on that parameter.  There's no reason for it to be there.  It's a reference type.  The ONLY reason to declare a reference type parameter `ref` is if you want to assign a different object to the parameter inside the method.  You only need `ref` if you passign out a different object than you passed in.  Setting properties, adding items to collections and even setting elements of arrays are NOT things that require a parameter declared `ref`.  Get rid of it and it will work as you want.

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. I tried to manually set a CustomCombox instance to a new KryptonComboBox() and got an error. I had a look through the method and only saw changes to the combo box, but it was never set to a completely new instance. I've removed the ref and it works fine.

Comment: All's well that ends well.  You may want to spend a bit more time reading up on value types and reference types and the implications of passing by value and by reference.  For value types, i.e. structures, you need to pass by reference in order that assigning a new object or changing the existing object affect the original argument.  For reference types, i.e. classes, you only need to pass by reference for assigning new objects.  Changing the existing object affects the original when passing by value.  That's because passing reference types by value copies the reference, not the object.